# Java web application internationalization issue

Tags: java, web-applications, localization, internationalization, globalization

I have a form in which I copied a Hindi text - "उदाहरण" from Google translator into a text field. When I submit the form at server I use `net.sf.json.JSONObject` library to parse the data as the data is sent in JSON format. When I do `jsonData.getString('textfield');` I get the string as ??????. This value is then persisted in MySQL database. I guess it is encoding issue that too at server. I checked in firebug the data is sent correctly. I am using Netbeans IDE, Glassfish server and MySQL as the database.

Comment: The problem is the way you read data from the server; you probably fail to specify the correct encoding. Code?

Comment: Try setting utf-8 in request encoding using servlet filter.

Comment: This could be a number of things but you didn't post any code. Ensure you are [encoding/decoding the data correctly](http://jsonunicode.sourceforge.net/) and that you are not losing data due to some lossy display mechanism (like non-Unicode output stream.)